# $tr(A)=tr(A^2)=tr(A^3) \implies A$ is Nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, nilpotence

> Let $A$ be a square matrix with $\mathrm{tr}(A)=\mathrm{tr}(A^2)=\mathrm{tr}(A^3)$. Prove that $A$ is nilpotent.

The tip in the question is to find the matrix $B$ which is similar to $A$ and then $A^2 \sim B^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework. Also, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type your questions. If you don't show some effort writing your questions, they will probably be closed.

Comment: The claim does not appear to be true for $A=I$...

Answer (score 2):

As trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of eigevalues $\lambda_i$ and we know that eigenvalues of a matrix powers are equal to powers of eigenvalues from conditions of a task we can obtain

$\sum   \lambda_i=\sum   \lambda_i^2=\sum   \lambda_i^3$

Such conditions are satisfied for $\lambda_i=0$ or $\lambda_i=1$.
Nilpotent matrix has only eigenvalues $0$ hence we see that broader class of matrices can satisfy conditions shown in the question.